# PayPal IPN Handshake Error

Tags: ssl, paypal, opencart, paypal-ipn

I am getting an IPN Handshake Error on the IPN Simulator. I've read some sources saying that I might be lacking certificates on the server. So I tried out some SSL commands to check on any issues.

First, I ran this command but did not go through as planned.

- *openssl s_client -connect api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com:443 -showcerts -CApath /etc/ssl/certs* - **Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)**

I had to specify the ***ca-bundle.crt*** file path and it went well.

- *openssl s_client -connect api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com:443 -showcerts -CAfile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt* - **Verify return code: 0 (ok)**

So I am thinking if there are ways to specify the certificate file path when performing cURL requests on OpenCart? Appreciate any assistance. Thanks.

Comment: I've been noticing the simulator returning lots of failures lately on IPN solutions that are working just fine.  I would recommend setting up an actual button from a sandbox account and completing a purchase through that button with a sandbox buyer account.  Make sure the seller account has IPN configured and you should see that it gets triggered and works as expected.  I have numerous IPN solutions setup in different places and they're all giving me an error with the simulator lately, but they all work just fine with actual transactions.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Andrew. Actually, I use the OpenCart tool for PayPal transaction and just checked on the ssl command. Apparently, I am getting the same result. Additional info, this is working well on dev server but not on the production. I compared the certificates installed on both servers and found out that production server has this ca-bundle.crt (i think this is just the concatenated version) while the dev server has multiple certificates. I'm wondering where could I set the actual file location of ca-bundle.crt on OpenCart.